# facebook graph explorer how to get only page's posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I need to get a page's posts. But only page's posts, I don't want to get users posts on that page .For example 
673049752787143/feed returns me https://www.facebook.com/147078515339869/posts/666313296749719 this post too. But I don't need this. Is there a way of doing this ?

---

I found my answer.
**/{page-id}/posts** shows only the posts that were published by this page.
This is what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This FQL should give you the info you want:

```
select post_id, message, attachment from stream where source_id="147078515339869" and actor_id="147078515339869"
```

As far as I know there's no way to do this with normal Graph API requests.